# Rails console setting limit to one on queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-console, ruby-on-rails-4.2

When I run ActiveRecord queries, the Rails Console seems to be appending `LIMIT 1` to my queries.

So I have a `sheet` which `has_many` `slots`.  When I query `Slot.find_by(sheet_id: 96)`, I get:

```
Slot Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "slots".* FROM "slots" WHERE "slots"."sheet_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["sheet_id", 96]]
=> #<Slot id: 153, label: "Foo", name: "Foo", email: "", phone: "", comments: "Fighters", sheet_id: 96, created_at: "2015-04-30 14:28:47", updated_at: "2015-04-30 14:28:47">
```

But when I query `Sheet.find(96).slots`:

```
Sheet Load (10.0ms)  SELECT  "sheets".* FROM "sheets" WHERE "sheets"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 96]]
Slot Load (4.6ms)  SELECT "slots".* FROM "slots" WHERE "slots"."sheet_id" = ?  [["sheet_id", 96]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Slot id: 153, label: "Foo", name: "Foo", email: "", phone: "", comments: "Fighters", sheet_id: 96, created_at: "2015-04-30 14:28:47", updated_at: "2015-04-30 14:28:47">, #<Slot id: 154, label: "Bar", name: "James", email: "", phone: "", comments: "Foobar", sheet_id: 96, created_at: "2015-04-30 14:28:47", updated_at: "2015-04-30 14:28:47">, ... >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do `Slot.find_all_by_sheet_id(96)`

**EDIT** The above code should have worked. Although I use Rails 4.1.8. Try following as well:

```
Slot.where(:sheet_id => 338)
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `find_all_by_sheet_id'

Comment: Thanks Abhi.  Looks like `where` pulls all data but `find_by` limits to one record.

Answer (score 0):

The `find_by` method returns a single result, always.

If you want to get all of the slots for a particular sheet, there are a few options:

`Sheet.find(96).slots` or more likely `@sheet.slots` if you've already found the sheet

`Slot.where(sheet_id: 96)` would also work

To be clear, this has nothing to do with the Rails console and everything to do with the `.find_by` method.